# javascript object modification add key for the object

Tags: javascript

I need to add year, month, day for my object. This is my current string array

```
["2021-11-01","2021-11-02"]
```

I need to convert this as below

```
[{ year: 2021, month: 11, day: 01 }, { year: 2021, month: 11, day: 02 }]
```

How i do this conversion. thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into the Date object? What about the Intl object?

Comment: The only way to have something like `day: 01` is to use a string `day: '01'`.

Comment: Simply use `map` on the `arr` and then split it with `-` and the return the new object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the date into components, [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the strings to numbers using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), and create an object:

```js
const data = ["2021-11-01","2021-11-02"];

const result = data.map(d => {
  const [year, month, day] = d.split('-').map(v => parseInt(v));
  return {year, month, day};
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is this really how we want SO to work? Teaching people that they can just drop any zero-effort, zero-research question here, and people will fall over themselves to hand them the solution, just so they will be right back as soon as they hit the next beginner's obstacle? No thank you.

Comment: Also not the output the OP wanted.

Comment: Instead of pointless sarcasm, why not address my point?

Comment: @Andy The output OP wanted cannot be achieved due to numbers not keeping a 0 prefix. It's either `1` or `"01"`.

Comment: I'm fully aware of that which is why I made that comment directly under the question instead of answering a question that showed no effort. @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: This could be as simple as `const [year, month, day] = d.split('-'); return {year: +year, month: +month, day: +day};`. You could avoid one extra `map` with that